# Scoped tabs displayed as unordered list

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, slds

I am facing an issue with displaying scoped tabs. I am referring the link: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/scoped-tabs/ as I want the tabs to display as per the link. But my tabs are displaying as unordered list even after using the same block of code.

```
    <aura:component description="TabSetExample">

    <ltng:require styles="/resource/SL_CP_SLDS/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.css" />

    <div class="slds">
        <div class="slds-tabs_scoped">
            <ul class="slds-tabs_scoped__nav" role="tablist">
                <li class="slds-tabs_scoped__item slds-is-active" title="Item One" role="presentation"><a class="slds-tabs_scoped__link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="tab-scoped-1" id="tab-scoped-1__item">Item One</a></li>
                <li class="slds-tabs_scoped__item" title="Item Two" role="presentation"><a class="slds-tabs_scoped__link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-scoped-2" id="tab-scoped-2__item">Item Two</a></li>
                <li class="slds-tabs_scoped__item" title="Item Three" role="presentation"><a class="slds-tabs_scoped__link" href="javascript:void(0);" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="tab-scoped-3" id="tab-scoped-3__item">Item Three</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tab-scoped-1" class="slds-tabs_scoped__content slds-show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-scoped-1__item">Item One Content</div>
            <div id="tab-scoped-2" class="slds-tabs_scoped__content slds-hide" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-scoped-2__item">Item Two Content</div>
            <div id="tab-scoped-3" class="slds-tabs_scoped__content slds-hide" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tab-scoped-3__item">Item Three Content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

FYI, Can anyone please help me out where I am going wrong. The slds static resource which I am referring is a valid resource as well with latest version.

Also can anyone tell me how can I use dynamic tab names. The tab names comes from the picklist values.

[image: My current view]

Comment: It looks like Lightning Design System is not included in your component. Are you sure about the path to the css resource?

Comment: I had missed extends implementation in aura:application.
Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Why not use `<lightning:tabset variant="scoped">` and `<lightning:tab>`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using this component in the app then extend SLDS in application itself.

```
   <aura:application extends="force:slds">
```

Comment: Thanks @Arpit. I already fixed it. Yup, I missed that stuff in aura:application.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i dynamically iterate to create tabs that displays tab names which should come from picklist values.
I have a picklist field name specified in config property

Comment: Glad it helps you. For dynamic tab names, you can make a list of string from the picklist and iterate over that list to make tabs. Please do let me know if you face issue.